# Left shift + c and left shift + 2 don't result in C or @

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I need help figuring out what could be happening to my keyboard (Logitech K470): using left <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd> doesn't result in `C` nor `@`; instead, nothing happens with this combination, but everything else works perfectly. I've tried a number of things to solve this:

- Reinstalled Windows 10 with all the updates (worked for a day, then issue came back)
- Uninstalled the keyboard, rebooted, reinstalled it
- Updated the drivers
- Changed the keyboard layout
- Searched the registry for keycode scanmap changes, nothing was found
- Disabled sticky keys and all assistance configurations
- Installed PowerToys to remap <kbd>LShift</kbd> to <kbd>RShift</kbd> (worked for a while, then stopped)
- Remapped <kbd>LShift</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and it didn't work

My keyboard hasn't suffered any spillage nor physical damage, it woke this way one day and I'm completely at loss here, as it appears there's something happening to this specific physical key combination, as I mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>LShift</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> worked as it should.

What else could I do to verify what's happening to that key?

Comment: Test another keyboard would be the first step.

Comment: When you uninstalled/reinstalled the keyboard, was it the generic drivers via Device Manager or the Logitech [software](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024361233) (either Options or SetPoint)? If you uninstalled via Device Manager, did you tick the box to remove installation files _(if this isn't done, Windows auto-reinstalls the drivers upon reboot)_?

Comment: It works for sometime then automatically stops working. This is a software problem not keyboard's fault. First try it in safe mode if it works. If doesn't, try running a different os (like linux or windows 7 etc on live boot) and see if it is fixed.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have a Dell G5 notebook and its keyboard works without issues. I also tried a wired keyboard I have and it worked too, no problems.

Comment: @JW0914, it was generic drivers via Device Manager. I did ticked the box to remove installation files. I also have G hub installed and removed it, but it didin't solve the issue.

Comment: @BrolyLSSJ, I tried Safe mode, Ubuntu, Fedora and even Haiku. All shows the same issue. I connected the K470 to another computer and the issues remainfed, so I'm now thinking that something's up with the kyboard firmware...

Comment: Just saw that if i press Shift+c one after another really quick I get this:  `ccccccccccccCCcCCccccCCCcCcccCCccCCCcCCCcCcCC`. The same thing happens with Shift+2. The more I dig the less sense it makes...

Comment: @FabioRomeo Have you tried installing the Logitech software for the keyboard? Uninstalling the generic driver isn't possible via Device Manager, as it's baked into the OS - ticking that box for the generic driver will only remove any updates to the generic driver since the OS was last updated/installed _(depends on Windows version)_

Comment: @JW0914, I installed this: https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893 but nothing changed.

Comment: @FabioRomeo It's a hardware issue with the keyboard then - if it's under warranty, file a claim, else you'll likely need to find a broken K470 and swap the PCBs _(you can try disassembling it and cleaning the top of the PCB that interacts with the keys with 90% Isopropyl alcohol, however it seems more like firmware corruption/a failed or failing PCB component rather than an exterior issue)_.. Repairing a failed PCB component is possible by businesses like UBreakIFix that have a microscopic soldering station, however it would likely be as much or more than the keyboard is worth

Comment: I now think there's something messing up the computer. I plugged my wired keyboard and it worked fine... Until the keys Ctrl and F misteriously stopped working! What. The. Hell. I'm on my third keyboard now, wired, working for who knows how long...